# Comparing pair in Power BI with inner join: why is "the table empty"? Should "List.Difference" be used?

Tags: list, join, merge, powerbi, powerquery

I would like to compare two lists contained in two excel workbook (universe 1 and Univers 2) through Power BI.

Here is an example of my first file:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|        Rabit        |     Employer     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|      Rab19881       |     Batman678    |
|---------------------|------------------|
|      Rab19882       |    Batman679     |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

Here is an example of my second file:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|        Rabit        |     Employer     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|      Rab19881       |     Batman678    |
|---------------------|------------------|
|      Rab19882       |    Batman679     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|      Rab19883       |     Batman680    |
|---------------------|------------------|
|      Rab19884       |    Batman681     |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

Here is the output that I would like to get. I would like to know which pairs are only in the first workbook and which pairs are only in the second workbook:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
| Unique Rabit/Employer in Universe 1    |
|---------------------|------------------|
|      0                                 |
|---------------------|------------------|
| Unique Rabit/Employer in Universe 2    |
|---------------------|------------------|
|      5                                 |
|---------------------|------------------|
| List of unique rabit/Emplyer:          |
|---------------------|------------------|
|      Rab19883       |     Batman680    |
|---------------------|------------------|
|      Rab19884       |    Batman681     |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

I found the tutorial ( https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/excel-compare-two-lists ) and thus tried to reproduce it:

- I first did a inner join with both of my columns, which I then expanded
- I then did a new join, "left anti", with both columns of both files, and the result I has was "The table is emplty".

I thus cannot more forward.

In the Power Query editor, I have the following code (regarding the data comparison, not the input of the two worksheets):

```
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Changed Type1", {"Rabit", "Employer"}, #"Universe 2", {"Rabit", "Employer"}, "Universe 2", JoinKind.Inner),
    #"Expanded Universe 2" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Universe 2", {"Rabit", "Employer"}, {"Rabit.1", "Employer.1"}),
    #"Merged Queries1" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Expanded Universe 2", {"Rabit", "Employer"}, #"Universe 2", {"Rabit", "Employer"}, "Universe 2", JoinKind.LeftAnti),
    #"Expanded Universe 1" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries1", "Universe 2", {"Rabit", "Employer"}, {"Rabit.2", "Employer.2"}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Expanded Universe 1", each true)
in
    #"Filtered Rows"
```

Why is that?
Is there a better way?
How could I move forward?

Comment: It's not clear what the output is in general, as a function of inputs. Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Please include everything needed to ask your question in the post itself. Please give a [mre] that can be cut & pasted & run to show your current results. Especially for impossible results.

Comment: Thank you for advice and the redirection to the guidelines. I updated the question accordingly.

Comment: You still don't use words to say how output is a function of input. We have to guess from an example. "compare two lists" how? What's "unique"--do you want the intersection of the tables? PS Text tables help. It turns out that in ascii, no lines between rows is more concise. But in a code context give a table as tablularized initialization text per your system/language--because you need it as cut & paste & run code of your [mre]. For SQL, that typically involves a VALUES. And "minimal" includes giving the smallest representative example data. Unlikely to be tens of rows you happen to be using.

Comment: Ok, I am sorry. I tried to explain how output is a function of input.

Comment: You describe what you want via "compare" &" which pairs are only in the first workbook and which pairs are only in the second workbook". That is not clear. Nobody could take just that & return with code they know you want or returns your example result. "Use enough words." You describe your code--which is wrong so it doesn't describe what you want. Moreover you should be giving all code as text so we can cut & paste & run. You give a link to some other presentation but you should put just what is relevant as text in your question & you should explain what it has to do with your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to select **only one column** and in the join kind option in the merge window, choose Inner (Only Marching Rows). Screenshot below:

[image: Inner March - Power BI]

Comment: But I do not understand...I cannot do that because pairs of values are what is important. A rabbit might exist in both universe, but he might change employer and this would be new. Why did they indicate to do it for both columns in the web tutorial ?

Comment: You can  try 2 things. 1. Merge these two column in both Queries and then use Table Merge. Or 2. Table Join using one column and see if there are no matches. 2nd point will tell you what data matches

Comment: Could it be possible to provide more detail on the first possibility: "1. Merge these two column in both Queries and then use Table Merge."? Is it also valid to select both column in each workbooks and do a first blank query as "Left Anti" or "Right Anti"?